# Remove /#/ in url ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, url, localhost

I use ReactJS to create app, When i start app with `yarn start`, app will run with url: `localhost:3000/#/dashboard`.
Now, i want remove string `/#/` in url.
I am trying change but not done. Please help me change this
The template using: `https://coreui.io/react/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`https://coreui.io/react` is using the `HashRouter` from `react-router-dom`. This is the safest router available, so I would consider whether or not you want to change it.

If you do, in [App.js](https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template/blob/main/src/App.js) swap `HashRouter` for `BrowserRouter`.